# Debugging project with conditional AssemblyNames

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce

I'm trying to use multiple configurations to create separate ClickOnce builds that users can install simultaneously. For instance, I want a team to be able to have both production and test builds installed at the same time, and each deployment would be updated via ClickOnce independent of the other (e.g. production builds are updated once a month; test builds are updated weekly).

I've modified my .csproj file to have the following elements:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|x86'">
  <AssemblyName>SomeNameTest</AssemblyName>
  <ProductName>Some Name - Test</ProductName>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Prod|x86' ">
  <AssemblyName>SomeName</AssemblyName>
  <ProductName>Some Name</ProductName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This actually works: I'm able to publish deployments with `SomeName` and `SomeNameTest` publish keys so I'm able to install both concurrently. The problem is when I try to debug in Visual Studio. Visual Studio does not recognize these conditional AssemblyNames so it comes up with some default (e.g. `SomeDefaultName`), and looks for an executable with that name (`SomeDefaultName.exe`), only to not find one when I'm in the Test configuration because MSBuild produces `SomeNameTest.exe` instead. Thus, when I try to run the project within Visual Studio I get the following error message:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target '...\SomeDefaultName.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

How would I go about supporting multiple installations without breaking debugging? This would be solved easily if the name of the executable was not tied to the key that's used to differentiate different ClickOnce installation, but I believe that's not the case—both use `AssemblyName` from what I understand.

I suppose I could add a post-build event that copies the MSBuild-produced executable to a name that Visual Studio recognizes, but that seems like a bad hack.

Comment: The C# IDE gives you a pretty luke-warm exposure to what MSBuild can do.  And sure, it does not support a different executable name.  All you got is Project + Properties, Build tab, Output path.  Which is all you actually need, a different path is already good enough to keep two EXE files with the same name separate.  Don't fight the machine, you'll lose.

Comment: I just tried reverting the conditional changes I made manually and just changed the publish folder and URL, and it's not letting me install it side-by-side with the original install. It gives me this error when trying to run the ClickOnce installer: "You cannot start application ___ from this location because it is already installed from a different location." So as far as I can tell it's not possible to allow concurrent installs by just changing the path.